# link rows and sum values on rows and store as a new variable

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to create a new data frame where the cumulative sum of the values from a row meet a certain threshold, and the sum begins again. Essentially I am trying to link the rows in a data set where the sum of the rows in the new column are greater than or equal to 5, and represents the sum of the values in the pop column.

```
data <- data.frame(pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 5, 10, 10))

linked_frame <- data.frame(pop_cumulative = c(6, 9, 10, 5, 10, 10))
```

and the linked rows 1, 2, and 3 form the first row in the new linked data frame and linked rows 4 and 5 form the second row in the new data frame, and the other rows remain the same, given these are greater than or equal to 5. How would I run such a function?

Comment: I'm thinking you are going to need a loop or `Reduce` to do this properly. Do you need the indexes of the rows that are grouped for the output as well, or literally just the sums as shown in `linked_frame`?

Comment: thanks, it ideally would also have the indexes of the grouped rows as another variable, so for example, 1, 2, 3 would be the indexes of the first grouping and 4, 5 would be the indexes of another grouping